# $R = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and consider $R^n$ for any $n,m$. For what values of $m$ is $R$ a semisimple $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, semi-simple-rings

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and consider $R^n$ for any $n,m$. For what values of $m$ is $R$ a semisimple $R$-module?

$\textbf{Context:}$ I am interested for what $m$ would the image of an endomorphism of $R^n$ be a direct summand.

Comment: $R^n$ is semisimple iff $R$ is.

Comment: Of course! That is why I am asking for $R$ instead of $R^n$.

Comment: Surely $R$ is semisimple as an $R$-module iff $R$ is semisimple as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

Comment: So iff $m$ is square free?

Comment: Did you really mean to ask "For what values of $m$ is $R^n$ a semisimple $R$ module?"  Otherwise, $m$ is not mentioned in the question. It's like you're saying "Consider $R$, and a banana. For what values of banana is $R$ semisimple?"  One of your comments suggests not, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ is a semisimple $R$ module iff $m$ is a (nonzero) square-free integer.  This is well-known because a commutative semisimple ring cannot have nonzero nilpotents, and this is exactly the condition to ensure that.

$R^n$ is a semisimple $R$ module iff $R$ is.

So the answer to your 'context' question is that if $m$ is squarefree, the image will always be a summand, but if it is not squarefree, it will only sometimes be a summand.